# Can't find URL for Heroku repository

Tags: ios, heroku, opentok

I've been following https://github.com/opentok/learning-opentok-ios/tree/basics.step-7 to try and get a video app to work on iOS using the OpenTok SDK.

I've already published an app called dongu using https://dashboard.heroku.com/new?template=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fopentok%2Flearning-opentok-php&button-url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fopentok%2Flearning-opentok-php.  I thought the git URL was git@heroku.com:dongu.git, however it doesn't work.

```
Error log:

News-MacBook-Pro:Dongu michaelnares$ git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:dongu.git
News-MacBook-Pro:Dongu michaelnares$ git add --all
News-MacBook-Pro:Dongu michaelnares$ git push heroku master
error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:dongu.git'
News-MacBook-Pro:Dongu michaelnares$ git heroku git:remote -a dongu
git: 'heroku' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

Did you mean this?
    checkout
```

All I want to do is add a simple HTML file to my Heroku app, however I can't find the URL to push to master from.  Is there any way of finding it out?

Answer (score 1):

Try

> heroku git:remote -a dongu

then

> git push heroku master

Comment: Nope.  News-MacBook-Pro:~ michaelnares$ heroku git:remote -a dongu
 ▸    128: Command failed: git remote
 ▸    fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
 ▸    
News-MacBook-Pro:~ michaelnares$

Comment: No big deal though, because doing what was suggested in that link did the trick.

Comment: It looks like you're in the wrong directory. Even plain Git can't add a remote if it's not a repo first, much less Heroku.

If you want to learn the CLI, see: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#creating-a-heroku-remote

Answer (score 1):

It might not be a git repo yet.
Run `git init` first.

Answer (score 0):

Simply following the instructions in https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/dongu/deploy/heroku-git did the trick, without me needing to know the remote URL, hopefully that's useful for anyone else having this problem.